# python manage.py collectstatic not working: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I have been following this video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inQyZ7zFMHM1

My project so far is working fine with static files and all the files load and work properly. So, now I have to deploy the website on Heroku and for that, I uploaded the database on Amazon AWS using this video.

After bucket creation, I did the configurations as mentioned in the video (copied the static files into the Bucket AWS) but it didn't work for me. It always showed me an error, that `failed to load the resources`

On searching, I found the command `python manage.py collectstatic` to upload files into Bucket so I tried it out but this is the error I keep on getting

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found`

I have searched a lot on this but unable to figure out what is the issue. *This is also the same error which I got when I myself uploaded static files into Bucket and tried to upload a Profile Image*

My `settings.py` file is as follows,

```
"""
Django settings for fcap project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os 
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-(c&774q+skzfb=n499li8!!!jv_m&s65eli3#w&zl+%c8h%sb$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

MESSAGE_TAGS = {

    messages.DEBUG: 'alert-info',
    messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
    messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
    messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
    messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
    
}

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fcap_users',
    'rest_framework',
    'storages', 
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fcap.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'fcap.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'fcap_db',
        'USER': 'asad_hussain',
        'PASSWORD': '(hidden for purpose)',
        'HOST': 'database-2.cfhvhdusomqt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432', 
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fcap/static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = "/images/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# S3 Bucket Config 
AWS_KEY_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '(hidden)'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '(hidden)'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'asad-hussain-fcap'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False 
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None 
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
```

This is my `requirements.txt`

```
asgiref==3.5.2
boto3==1.24.50
botocore==1.27.50
Django==4.1
django-filter==22.1
django-storages==1.13.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
jmespath==1.0.1
Markdown==3.4.1
multielo==0.4.1
numpy==1.23.1
pandas==1.4.3
Pillow==9.2.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
s3transfer==0.6.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.11
validate-email==1.3
```

My File Structure is as follows,

[image]

All the static files are working fine if they are on localhost but not working after the connection with AWS. ***However, the Postgres database is uploaded on AWS and it is working fine (that is, I can create users and etc using the AWS Database and they work fine.)***

Comment: You've shared your aws db creadentials & all secrets inside your question it's good practice to hide these sensitive info don't share it publically. Use some tools like [djang-environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/), [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) to hide it

Comment: @AnkitTiwari it's my first time working with this so that's why. I could have used .env though for sure. I will be more careful next time. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: You should also now revoke the access key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mispelled `AWS_KEY_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

It should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

The program expects a string against `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` but because it is mispelled, so it is getting `None` instead. Due to this reason, you are getting an error that `NoneType Found`

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the 'STATICFILES_DIRS' and try again. That was only used in my development.

also on a side note, i would remove the access keys from your bucket config when posting here. Even in production, they shouldn't be seen there. You can use a JSON config file or another method thats not accessable.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried commenting out `STATICFILES_DIRS` but it gives the same error. Tried it again, and got the same error. 
(And you are right, I am sorry its my first time working with AWS. I have removed the access keys now. Thank you for the note)